# redirect function is not working when it takes time in processing

Tags: codeigniter, redirect

I am using form. I am unable to redirect after completion of process. It is working proper when I have less amount of data for processing but when data is high, it is taking time 10 to 15 minutes and here it is unable to redirect on another location.
following this

```
view.php

doing my work
after completing functionality. 


 $controller->redirect_function($path);
```

controller.php

```
function redirect_function($path){
   redirect($path);
   }
```

Please help

Comment: Why not put the processing into a queue and process it in the background. This would mean that the user would not be held up while processing is taking place. You could put the processing call into a cronjob on your server.

Comment: It will not take much time always, it is not working only for large amount of data. Here my concern is redirection only.

Answer (score 0):

Your script must be dying before completion because of the timeout value set in your php.ini.
You can use [set-time-limit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) function to increase the maximum time a script can run.

Comment: I am also using unlimited time limit by using this set_time_limit(0) function

Comment: try to log after completing your functionality and check if log is written. Also one reason of redirect not happening would be because of connection time out by browser. Look at this https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/998088